# font name to use in CGSize sizeWithFont:?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I just want to use the iPhone system font but I can't figure out what to call it.  sizeWithFont:@"HelveticaNeue" gives me a bad parameter error.  sizeWithFont:System gives me an uninitialized variable error.  It seems like it should be so obvious but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs:

```
- [NSString sizeWithFont:]
```

takes an `UIFont` as its argument, and not an `NSString`. You should use something like

```
[string sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0]]
```

instead.